# Trouble using mouseover on ad in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, mouseevent, ads

As part of a Chrome extension, I'm trying to detect when you hover on an ad.  Right now, I'm only testing on the NYT frontpage.  The problem area of the content script is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("starting...");
        console.log(document.querySelectorAll("iframe"));
        var frames = $("iframe").contents().find(".ad-frame.frame-for-homepage");
        console.log(frames);

        frames.on("mouseover", function(event){
            console.log("on ad");
        });
    }, 10000);


});
```

The setTimeout function is a hack specific to getting the right iframes on the page.  The console.log shows that it picks out the correct iframes containing the ads, but the mouseover event doesn't fire.  It actually appears that it won't run anything past the querySelectorAll line, because no further console.logs appear.

If I move the mouseover outside of the setTimeout function, it fires on mouseover of any element on the page.

I've hit a bit of a wall with this so any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector is incorrect, you can simplify your code to make it work as the ad `iframe`s have the classes `.ad-frame.frame-for-homepage`. This works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    setTimeout(function() {

        console.log("starting...");
        console.log(document.querySelectorAll("iframe"));
        var frames = $("iframe.ad-frame.frame-for-homepage");
        console.log(frames);

        frames.on("mouseover", function(event){
            console.log("on ad");
        });

    }, 10000);

});
```

Edit: tested it as a Chrome extension and it works fine, the console logs "on ad" when mousing over the ads, except the flash one on top (I checked and the iframe has `height:0`)

Comment: "First, you need to use `jQuery()` instead of `$()`" Wait, what? Why?

Comment: @Xan because as the question says: "I'm only testing on the NYT frontpage", I tested on the NYT page and OP's code worked changing `$()` with `jQuery()` to avoid conflict

Comment: There is a jQuery conflict using $, OP has to use `jQuery()` instead of `$()`

Comment: This is not how content scripts work. There is no conflict, since it's [an isolated context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment). For a content script, page's JavaScript simply does not exist.

Comment: Ok, I'll update the answer with that suggestion. Thanks for the comment. I didn't create an extension just tested from the console.

Comment: "just tested from the console": this may present a problem; you're not reproducing the situation, because you're testing against the page's context/origin/jQuery version. In theory.

Comment: Thanks, Alvaro. The selector was my issue. As others noted, $() vs jQuery() didn't produce a conflict because of how the content-scripts work. Appreciate your help.